# Typescript keyof extra type condition

Tags: typescript, typescript2.4

I want pass two generic condition for pass array type field name but not accepted second condition.

This my method declaration and this no problem.

```
firstOrDefault<K extends keyof T>(predicate?: (item: T) => boolean, recursiveItem?: K): T;
```

Above method declaration is working but I want pass only Array type in recurviseItem field.

I'm trying this method declaration but doesn't work.

```
firstOrDefault<K extends keyof T & T[]>(predicate?: (item: T) => boolean, recursiveItem?: K): T
```

How can solve this problem?

**Sample Code**

```
let departments : IDepartment[] = [
    {
        name: 'manager',
        subDepartments: [
            {
                name: 'accountant'
            }
        ]
    }
]

// This my method declaration and this code worked but you can pass name and subDepartments field pass for recursiveItem parameter but i want only T[] type field pass so only subDepartments.
let department = departments.firstOrDefault(d => d.name == 'accountant', 'subDepartments')
console.log(department)

interface Array<T> {
    firstOrDefault<K extends keyof T>(predicate?: (item: T) => boolean, recursiveItem?: K): T;
}

Array.prototype.firstOrDefault = function(this, predicate, recursiveItem) {
    if (!predicate)
        return this.length ? this[0] : null;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        let item = this[i]
        if (predicate(item))
            return item
        if (recursiveItem) {
            let subItems = item[recursiveItem]
            if (Array.isArray(subItems)) {
                var res = subItems.firstOrDefault(predicate, recursiveItem)
                if (res)
                    return res
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

interface IDepartment {
    name?: string,
    subDepartments?: IDepartment[]
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `recursiveItem?: K[]`, then? That would be an array of things that are keys of `T`.

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having, Tried to compile your code in ts 2.5 and both versions work (I assumed they were declared in a generic type with a T parameter,

Comment: do you want to say that `recursiveItem` can be either an array of `T` or a `key of T` ?

Comment: firstOrDefault is an array prototype method and i want only array type field for recursiveItem parameter.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for your comment, your suggestion unfortunately incorrent because `K[]` declaration only was such as fieldName[] for example i'm passed `firstName` for recursiveItem parameter and result that => 'firstName'[] unfortunately incorrect. I want this result => `T['fieldName']:T[]`

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer, because I'm trying to figure out what you want. Could you show an example usage?

Comment: Sorry, I'm added now example code.

Comment: @MuratÖNER You should write `let subItems = item[recursiveItem]` to make your code work.

Comment: I've you've solved the problem, *write a proper answer*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this type definition

```ts
type ArrayProperties<T, I> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<I> ? K : never }[keyof T]

class A {
    arr1: number[];
    arr2: string[];
    str: string;
    num: number;
    func() {}
}

let allArr: ArrayProperties<A, any>; // "arr1" | "arr2"
let numArr: ArrayProperties<A, number>; // "arr1"
```

so `firstOrDefault` would look like that (I put `ArrayProperties<T, T>` to restrict recursiveItem only for recursive type i.e. only properties of type `IDepartment[]` could be used, however you can put `ArrayProperties<T, any>` if you want to accept any array)

```
function firstOrDefault<T>(predicate?: (item: T) => boolean, recursiveItem?: ArrayProperties<T, T>): T { }
```

With your example

```
interface IDepartment {
    name: string;
    subDepartments?: IDepartment[];
}

let departments : IDepartment[] = [
    {
        name: 'manager',
        subDepartments: [
            {
                name: 'accountant'
            }
       ]
    }
]

let a = firstOrDefault(((d: IDepartment) => d.name === 'accountant'), 'subDepartments'); // OK
let b = firstOrDefault(((d: IDepartment) => d.name === 'accountant'), 'subDepartment'); // error: [ts] Argument of type '"subDepartment"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"subDepartments"'.
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a great answer.  What you are looking for is a type function that identifies the properties of a type `T` whose values are of type `Array<T>` (or `Array<T> | undefined` since optional properties are like that).  This would be most naturally expressed by [mapped conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12424), which are not yet part of TypeScript.  In that case, you could make something like

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
type RestrictedKeys<T> = ValueOf<{
  [K in keyof T]: If<Matches<T[K],Array<T>|undefined>, K, never>
}>
```

and annotate the `recursiveItem` parameter as type `RestrictedKeys<T>` and be done.  But you can't do that.

---

The only solution I've that actually works is to give up on extending the `Array` prototype.  (That's bad practice anyway, isn't it?)  If you are okay with a standalone function whose first parameter is an `Array<T>`, then you can do this:

```
function firstOrDefault<K extends string, T extends Partial<Record<K, T[]>>>(arr: Array<T>, pred?: (item: T) => boolean, rec?: K): T | null {
    if (!pred)
        return this.length ? this[0] : null;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        let item = this[i]
        if (pred(item))
            return item
        if (rec) {
            let subItems = item[rec]
            if (Array.isArray(subItems)) {
                var res = firstOrDefault(subItems, pred, rec)
                if (res)
                    return res
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the above, you can restrict the type `T` to be a `Partial<Record<K,T[]>>`, meaning that `T[K]` is an optional property of type `Array<T>`.  By expressing this as a restriction on `T`, the type checker behaves as you'd like:

```
firstOrDefault(departments, (d:IDepartment)=>d.name=='accountant', 'subDepartments') // okay
firstOrDefault(departments, (d:IDepartment)=>d.name=='accountant', 'name') // error
firstOrDefault(departments, (d:IDepartment)=>d.name=='accountant', 'random') // error
```

---

As I said, there's no great way to take the above solution and make it work for extending the `Array<T>` interface, since it works by restricting `T`.  In theory, you could express `K` in terms of `T`, like `keyof (T & Partial<Record<K,T[]>>`, but TypeScript does not aggressively evaluate intersections to eliminate impossible types, so this still accepts `name`, even though the inferred type of the `name` property would be something like `string & IDepartment[]` which shouldn't exist.

Anyway, hope the above solution can work for you.  Good luck!

---

EDIT: I see you've solved your own problem by relaxing a different requirement: the `recursiveItem` parameter is no longer a key name.  I still think you should consider the standalone function solution, since it works as you originally intended and doesn't pollute the prototype of `Array`.  It's your choice, of course.  Good luck again!

Comment: Thanks for answer but i don't see your partial and record object. I want try your suggestion.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm finded partial and record object from this url https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html